# Retrieving AJAX content from TWebBrowser after page load

Tags: ajax, delphi, twebbrowser

I am currently using this code to retrieve the content as string **after** it is has been rendered by TWebBrowser and you visually can see it shows the content loaded dynamicly through AJAX:

```
function TMyViewerIE.GetDocumentAsStr: string;
begin
if Assigned(FWebBrowser.Document) then
  begin
    iall := (FWebBrowser.Document AS IHTMLDocument2).body;
    while iall.parentElement <> nil do
    begin
      iall := iall.parentElement;
    end;
    Result := iall.outerHTML;
  end
;
end;
```

However, this code does not appear to include changes performed by AJAX.

---

**Note:** For those who believe above code is "out of context", please also see this SO where a variation of this code was suggested as a solution:

[Delphi TWebBrowser get HTML source after AJAX load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517802/delphi-twebbrowser-get-html-source-after-ajax-load)

Problem is that it does not work for me. I had thought above would work since (again I thought) AJAX changes the internal document structure and that was what was saved.

Maybe I am missing something - if anyone knows the answer, I will appreciate it. I will also continue my own research and post results.

**Note:** I may try construct an AJAX page (or public / goverment page) so I can share my test cases more easily. I believe that will satisfy suggestions about a working example.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. *This code totally out of context doesn't work* is not meaningful, and while your title says (what I think is) *Fetching Ajax*, the code does absolutely nothing to fetch anything. How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: @KenWhite If you have webrowser load a page - that is the code one would use as-is to get it into a string when using TWebBrowser. It works but does not grab content changed through Javascript/AJAX. You will find a variation of that code as a solution to a similar question on SO. Problem is that it does not work for me.

Comment: I don't care that *a variation of that code* is in an answer to a similar question. What matters is what you've posted here, which is not something that can be used by us to reproduce the issue. Please read my previous comment again. (And the word is *fetching*, as I also mentioned in my prior comment; you really should fix it in the title while editing to add the code for your [mcve].)

Comment: TWebBrowser works well for you ?. I switched to Embedded Chromium (you just need to distribute the libraries of that framework with your application) and it works much better for me.  https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3